# Equating coefficients of an inequality

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I am struggling to understand a technique where coefficients are compared on two sides of an inequality. It is given that:

$$
3n^2 - n - B + 3Bn \ge 4An^2 - An
$$

Where $n > 1$ and that $A$ and $B$ are positive constants. We are asked to explain why $A \le 3/4$.

The mark scheme says:

> Comparing coefficients of $n^2$ (the dominant term), we need $3 \ge 4A$ so that $A \le 3/4$.

I'm familiar with the technique of equating coefficients across an equals sign, but am confused to its use here. Is this a general technique or is it a special case? Is there any concern with negatives that doesn't matter here since everything is positive?

(This question comes from Q3 of MAT 2009, [questions](https://www.maths.ox.ac.uk/system/files/attachments/test09.pdf), [answers](https://www.maths.ox.ac.uk/system/files/attachments/websolutions09.pdf)).

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Alternate approach: If you are familiar with quadratic equations and their graphs, you can try expressing the given inequality as $(3-4A)n^2+(A-3B-1)n-B\geq 0$, which is a quadratic inequality in $n$. Since this inequality holds true for all $n\gt 1$, we must have $\text{coefficient of } n\gt 0$, and hence $A\lt \frac 34$. But I am unable to prove the equality part of the question.

Comment: Thanks RiverX15. I think the next part of the question asks about the behavior when $A = \frac{3}{4}$ since it collapses into a straight line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is that the the given function is nonnegative for large $n,$ and its graph comprises discrete points that form either a parabola or a straight line.

This is possible only when it's the latter or when the parabola is smiley, i.e., when the coefficient of $n^2$ is either zero or positive, respectively. So, we need $3\geq4A$ or, equivalently, $3-4A\geq0.$

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Is the function in this case $(3−4A)n^2 +(A−3B−1)n−B$? I think I understand what you mean about making sure the parabola can't be negative. I just can't wrap my head around why it's necessarily positive for any $n > 1$... is there no value of $B$ that could push it below the $x$-axis? Desmos shows that this isn't the case (https://www.desmos.com/calculator/hlcgb2us3c) but I can't think how to see that without a graphing calculator. Thank you again :)

Comment: @OllyBritton 1. I think you mean $3B+A-1$ for the second coefficient. 2. "*I think I understand what you mean about making sure the parabola can't be negative*" .... **for large n**. It is give that the function is nonegative for $n>1;$ this includes when $n$ is large, for which a parabola will either be also very positive (which is our given case) or very negative (which contradicts our given case). the fomer corresponds to smiley parabola, the latter to sad parabola.

Comment: Ah, my misunderstanding is that we don't actually have to prove that it's positive. I'm a happy parabola now